# Testing write(byte[]) on FileOutputStream vs. BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, performance, bufferedoutputstream

Is there an actual performance difference when using `write(byte[])` methods from `FileOutputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`?

I tested both on HDD to write 500 MB file and the result was 13 and 12 seconds:

```
try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath1)) {
            out.write(readBytes);
}
```

and,

```
try(BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( 
                           new FileOutputStream(filePath2))) {
            out.write(readBytes);
}
```

What am I missing about `BufferedOutputStream` efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedOutputStream` is more efficient if you're writing data a little bit at a time: it batches the writes until it has "enough" data.

If you're writing it all at once, there's going to be no difference, because there's always enough data to fill the buffer; or you've reached the end of the data and need to close the stream.

Comment: So, it will make a difference in only writing byte by byte i.e. write(int b)?

Comment: Doesn't have to be one at a time; it's just if it's less than the buffer size (which is 8192 by default).

Comment: As an addendum, if the array (fragment) to be written is as big or equal to the buffer size, the `BufferedOutputStream` will go out of the way and pass the array to the target stream directly. As a consequence, the worst case would be to repeatedly write chunks slightly smaller than the buffer size, which will not reduce the number of target write operations significantly, but add a copying overhead. In that case, the `BufferedOutputStream` *reduces* the performance.